# skip first number, reading int from file java

Tags: java, file, int, java.util.scanner

Trying to read int from file. My problem is that my code read all the integers in the first line, but on the succeeding line it skips the first number.
To illustrate my file has these numbers:
1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 9, 
1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 
2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 0,

but when i use the code below it only prints 1 4 6 7 8 11 9 then 4 6 7 8 11 12 then 2... it skips the first no.

```
Scanner file = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> listtwo = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        file = new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt")).useDelimiter(",| ");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(file.hasNext()){
        if (file.hasNextInt()){ 
            listtwo.add(file.nextInt());
        }
        file.next();
    }
    for (Integer i: listtwo) System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: @ambigram_maker Wrong. `hasNext...()` methods do not skip anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your

```
file.next();
```

Remove it.

Comment: Oh, forgot to notice this one! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
while(file.hasNext()){
        if (file.hasNextInt()){ 
            listtwo.add(file.nextInt());
        }
        file.next();
    }
```

to EDIT

```
int i = 0;
while(file.hasNextInt()){
   listtwo[i++] = file.nextInt();
}
```

In your code, it is first searching for the next "word" in the text file. The "if" statement then tells it to find the next int after that first "word", thus it skips the first number of the line.

Comment: Yes. Of course, I haven't tested this exact code myself. But theoretically, it works.

Comment: Try something like this                                           int i = 0;
while(file.hasNextInt()){
   listtwo[i++] = file.nextInt();
}

Comment: the lastline is only for array not arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Use like this   file.next(); will run twise if you have file.hasNextInt() is true to avoid that use else case.

```
     while(file.hasNext()){
    if (file.hasNextInt()){ 
        listtwo.add(file.nextInt());
    }else{
       file.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: same result, it still skips